# C++ - How to debug issue where application is consuming too much memory?

Tags: c++, windows, memory

I am investigating a problem in a C++/WTL application where a recent change in the software is causing a larger amount of memory to be consumed (when viewing the memory usage in the Windows taskbar). This only happens when the user has a certain window opened in the software (so I know that the issue is isolated to this area of the code). The nature of the changes involve adding another piece of information to a key object. So now each key entry of certain maps in the software is a 4 part key instead of a 3 part key like it was before. So my theory is that this is causing a lot more values to be added to various maps which in turn consumes a lot more memory. I'm trying to determine the best method for proving this. Should I just add debug code that prints out the sizes of these maps? If this turns out to not be a problem (it's possible that the changes are causing a ripple effect somewhere else), then where I do start when debugging an issue like this? I do not think that this is a memory leak issue (I suppose it's possible though) but rather an issue where adding complexity to a data structure is causing a ripple effect from a memory perspective.

Comment: Well firstly task manager is not very accurate at memory usage. And of course you should check how much memory your data structures consume.

Comment: What tool should I use then?